# Renaming windows of shells in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, terminal

How can you rename windows in Ubuntu?

I have a few terminals open. 
All of them have the name "Untitled window".
I would like to rename them similarly as you can in Screen by `C-A A`.

Comment: @DavidCole Please, provide us a link to the duplicate thread in askubuntu.

Comment: Please [migrate](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85017/moving-my-own-question-to-another-stack-exchange-site) this question to [AskUbuntu](http://www.askubuntu.com) where the help would be more appreciated and needed ***;)*** This question was [asked earlier](http://askubuntu.com/questions/729639/how-to-give-each-terminal-tab-its-own-title)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The process is a little complex to explain here since it is different for every shell you use. Rather I'll give you two links:

- [How to Change the Title of an
  xterm](http://www.faqs.org/docs/Linux-mini/Xterm-Title.html#ss4.3) (Comprehensive instructions
  for many different shells)
- [Show the current Command in your
  Bash window Title](http://www.davidpashley.com/articles/xterm-titles-with-bash.html). A nice step by
  step procedure on how the author went
  on to do this nice effect. Makes for
  a good learning practice. (But bash
  specific)

There are a few other things to take into consideration. For a one time change common to all terminal sessions, you may want instead to simply alter Bash (if you use bash and under gnome) icon and add `--title=title` under Gnome.

Answer (score 3):

For terminal windows I set

> PROMPT_COMMAND='echo -ne "\033]0;xterm${XUSER} $$ ${USER}@${HOSTNAME}:${PWD}\007"'

in .bashrc (if $TERM is xterm or rxvt) to get pid, pwd et all in the window title. Further set XUSER=/someTask to put task related info into the terminal window title.

Answer (score 1):

You could install and use `xttitle` (Note the doubled `t` in the name). I use it like this in a file sourced by my `~/.bashrc`:

```
# from the "xttitle(1)" man page - put info in window title
update_title()
{
    [ $TERM = xterm -o $TERM = xterm-color ] && xttitle "[$$] ${USER}@${HOSTNAME}:$PWD"
}

cd()
{
    [ -z "$*" ] && builtin cd $HOME
    [ -n "$*" ] && builtin cd "$*"
    update_title
}
```

I also do this:

```
xttitle Mutt && mutt
```